# Python adding unique string into array

Tags: python, arrays, string, conditional-statements

ok this is more of a conceptual question, but if i have an array of strings, how can i make a condition where i have a program that tracks a chat and prints out the players name, how can i make a condition where i have a loop that prints the players name every time they chat once i turn on the program, but if they chat again, and my program recognizes the familiar name, it wont print their name out again, essentially only printing out that persons name once

```
    userName = "ThePlayersName" # constantly changing

    nameTracker = []

    if userName not in nameTracker:
        

        print(userName)
```

I understand the program is wrong, but just assume 'UserName' is constantly changing and the userName is being added to the array, or another way to print out the name only once

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array, you could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which can contain only distinct elements. You can use `nameTracker.add(userName)` and it will only add the name if it's not already in the set.

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work just fine.

```py
userName = "ThePlayersName"  # constantly changing

nameTracker = []


def printUser(name):
    if name not in nameTracker:
        print(name)


printUser(userName)

nameTracker.append(userName)

printUser("Player 2")

nameTracker.append("Player 2")

printUser("Player 2")
```

prints

```
ThePlayersName
Player 2
```